# How to make VBA for Access to check for record data not entered in login form?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a table with the fields UserLogin, password, Names, and SecurityLvl. I also have a form that has 2 input boxes for UserLogin and password, and checks if that information is right. I was wondering if there is a way to check if the SecurityLvl is Admin, Student, or Professor for the same ID that logged in through UserLogin and password. Here is my code for the login button below.

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()
Dim AccessLvl As String
'If there is no password or username then shows pop-up
'usertext is username box and passtext is password box
If IsNull(Me.usertext) Then
    MsgBox "Please enter login", vbInformation, "LOGIN REQUIRED"
    Me.usertext.SetFocus
ElseIf IsNull(Me.passtext) Then
    MsgBox "Please enter password", vbInformation, "PASSWORD REQUIRED"
    Me.passtext.SetFocus
'Sets actual values from table to values started above and checks if username and password actually match up with table
Else
   If (IsNull(DLookup("[UserLogin]", "LoginTable", "[UserLogin] ='" & Me.usertext.Value & "'  and password = '" & Me.passtext.Value & "'"))) Then
    MsgBox "Username/password not valid"
    Else
        MsgBox "Login successful"
    End If
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: You could do another DLookup() with the usertext.Value as criteria.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DLookup can look and return multiple (concatenated) fields, therefore you could try something like this, with a few minor changes:

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()

    Dim retValue As Variant, AccessLvl As String

    With Me
        Select Case True
            Case IsNull(.usertext.Value):
                MsgBox "Please enter login", vbInformation, "LOGIN REQUIRED"
                .usertext.SetFocus

            Case IsNull(.passtext.Value):
                MsgBox "Please enter password", vbInformation, "PASSWORD REQUIRED"
                .passtext.SetFocus

            Case Else:
                retValue = DLookup("[UserLogin] & ',' & [SecurityLvl]", "LoginTable", "[UserLogin] ='" & .usertext.Value & _
                                                                                      "'  and password = '" & .passtext.Value & "'")

                'This will return a string in the form of "User,AccessRights"
                'Just split the string where the comma is and get the second part. 
                'The username is the first part so it can be obtained using 
                'Split(retValue, ",")(0) 

                If IsNull(retValue) Then
                    MsgBox "Username/password not valid"
                    Exit Sub
                End If

                AccessLvl = Split(retValue, ",")(1)
                MsgBox "Login successful"
        End Select
    End With
End Sub
```